# Нарисовать разные слои так, чтобы не сбился весь дизайн

Tags: html, css

Есть страница, составленная из квадратиков как на фотографии ниже`(1)`. И все они расположены плотно друг к другу. Как можно нарисовать такую анимацию`(2)` при наведении мыши так, чтобы все остальное не сбивалось. Пытался с помощью `JS` открывать скрытые блоки, но тогда все сбивалось.

Можно ли сделать это как-то поверх всего? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
div{
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #c44444;
   }
```

```html
<div>Состав</div>
```

Comment: Под номером 2 это ховер?

Comment: @Cheg, да, hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.inner-1 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.inner-2 {
  background: #c44444;
}

.block:hover .inner {
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

А можно и с `box-shadow`:

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #c44444;
}

.block:hover .inner {
  transform: translate(20px, -20px);
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 0px #ccc, -20px 20px 0px #e9e9e9;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="inner inner">

  </div>
</div>
```